# Loop inside the function doesn't do what I want

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops, types

When I add an operation that I can do in the loop, I do not get an error, but the operation is not performed. With the loop I can perform the types of columns of a dataframe on a dataframe. but the operation I want to do as a function to generalize this is not complete. I am able to loop in the loop as follows.

I can convert the data type of those with less than 10 unique values in these columns to character by traversing the columns in the dataframe I named with data with a loop.

```
for (col in colnames(data)){
    if (length(unique(unlist(data[col]))) < 10){
    print(col)
    data[col] <- lapply(data[col], as.character)
  }
}
```

The function I wrote for this operation is as follows

```
numeric_to_cat <- function(dataframe){
  for (col in colnames(dataframe)){
    if (length(unique(unlist(dataframe[col]))) < 10){
    print(col)
    dataframe[col] <- lapply(dataframe[col], as.character)
    }
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work when I try to do the same operation inside a function.

```
numeric_to_cat <- function(dataframe){
  for (col in colnames(dataframe)){
    if (length(unique(unlist(dataframe[col]))) < 10){
    print(col)
    dataframe[col] <- lapply(dataframe[col], as.character)
    }
  }
}
```

I want to change the data type of the column according to a certain condition in different dataframes that can be entered with a function.

Comment: Add `return(dataframe)` after the for loop to return the dataframe.

Comment: You can do it without a loop: `data(mtcars); mtcars.mod <- as.data.frame(lapply(mtcars, function(x) if (length(unique(x)) < 10) as.character(x) else x))`.